# What kind of exception should go in the catch with assertEquals?

Tags: java, exception, selenium, webdriver, try-catch

I'm making a webdriver and part of it is to check the title to make sure that it is on the right page. Just for my benefit now I want it to show a dialog box when it the title doesn't match but right now all it does is give me an error message in the console. I believe it's my exception that is the problem. Any suggestions?

```
try{
    assertEquals("Current page title", "Account Inventory - Select Manager", pageTitle);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Message");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame ,
            "The title does not match");
}
```

Comment: Sorry my code looks a little weird. I'm not sure why it split it up like that.

Comment: *Why* do you want to show a dialog box rather than just logging the failure?

Comment: (The code looks weird because you didn't format it properly in Markdown. Always look at the preview and make your code readable *before* you post.)

Comment: Why do you want to use try/catch instead of: `if(!pageTitle.equals("Account Inventory - Select Manager")) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The title does not match");`? (Also note you don't need to create a frame; pass null for the frame instead of making a temporary one)

Comment: I've assumed in my answer that we're looking at test code here. Is that right?

Comment: I have 25 tests happening so I don't want the program to stop when it finds out that the assertion is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assertEquals` with throw an [`AssertionError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) when the condition is not met. So you should probably either catch that error explicitly, or widen your catch to include `Throwable` rather than `Exception`.

See the type hierarchy diagram below to understand why `catch (Exception e)` won't catch an `AssertionError`.

```
java.lang.Object
  |--- java.lang.Throwable
         |--- java.lang.Error
                | --- java.lang.AssertionError  // not a descendent of Exception
         |--- java.lang.Exception
```

However... tests are generally supposed to be automated so I can't imagine why you'd want to introduce a human element by showing a dialog.

Comment: the test will be automated the point of the dialog box is simply for my benefit while I'm testing to make sure that it works then I'll worry about the automation part later.

Comment: @Zach If you're using Eclipse or something there should be a fairly reasonable UI for running JUnit tests already there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, assertions are not for handling exceptions, they are for asserting some test cases. If an asserted case doesn't come to be true, then there is a serious problem with the input causing the problem which require special attention, that's why you get `AssertionError` when an assertion fails.

And I think you are mixing the intentions of using exceptions and errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is unit test code. 
You can handle it in 2 ways.

1. Catch the error and write error log.
2. Do not catch the exception and to allow a method further up the call stack to handle it